Percentage error using logarithms and differentials doesn't work with lens formula and similar relationships.
We're given a somewhat standard method for finding the percentage error of a quantity $Q^q = A^a B^b C^c \times ...$, we do this by taking log on both sides, and then taking a differential, thus:
$$
\Big|q\frac{dQ}{Q}\Big| = \Big|a\frac{dA}{A}\Big| + \Big|b\frac{dB}{B}\Big| + ...
$$
This is of course, only approximately true, and 'truer' for smaller values of $\frac{dX}{X}$.
(The thumbrule for our examination is that as long as no one of $\frac{dX}{X}$ is greater than 0.1 or 10%, nor is the final sum, we're good to go)
When trying to apply the procedure to the lens/mirror equation to find $\frac{df}{f}$, or similar relations (resistances in parallel, capacitors in series, etc.), we have
$$
\frac{1}{v} - \frac{1}{u} = \frac{1}{f}
$$
$$
\frac{u - v}{uv} = \frac{1}{f}
$$
$$
\frac{|du| + |dv|}{|u - v|} + \Big|\frac{dv}{v}\Big| + \Big|\frac{du}{u}\Big| = \Big|\frac{df}{f}\Big|
$$
We are however 'advised' (i.e. required) simply to take a differential to obtain:
$$
\Big|\frac{dv}{v^2}\Big| + \Big|\frac{du}{u^2}\Big| = \Big|\frac{df}{f^2}\Big|
$$
Now I'm aware the threshold of 'close enough' is quite arbitrary, but even for small $dX$s and large $X$s, the first expressions should yield answers that are close enough, no? Is there some numerical instability introduced by taking logarithms? Or where else may the first method not work?
